# How to disable Autocommit Mode in SSMS?

Tags: ssms

How can I disable the Autocommit Mode in SSMS?
I don't want it to save it all to make the transaction more sure. If the transaction is successful, it will complete and if it's not, it will fail for sure.

I think by default it's on in SSMS...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connect to SQL Server using SSMS

From the Menu bar, select Tools –> Options

Select Query Execution –> SQL Server –> ANSI

Make sure that you check the check box SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS

Click on OK